# Sign in with Slack with workspace email, email and password

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to integrate Slack in my app. The documentation explains how to sign in with Slack to a workspace with client ID. But I'd like to accomplish this situation:
-User enters workspace email
-User enters his email (which he used to sign up to the workspace)
-User enters his password (which he used to sign up to the workspace)
Can I perform a sign in request with the given information?

Comment: Please be more specific what you want kind of interaction your app is supposed to have with Slack. Do you just want to use Slack for user authentication? Or do you want to access the Slack workspace? Do you want to access a specific workspace only or do you want to access various workspaces based on the user account?

Comment: I just solved the problem creating a deep link to the app connected to the redirect uri of Slack app settings. I checked out part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39721012/6654061. The main purpose was to use Slack for user authentication and access to the workspace.

Comment: Awesome. Would appreciate if you could post the solution as answer, so that this question can be close.